# Balanced payments PCI complaince with ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

I am curious if I use the [balance-ruby](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby) gem and the guidelines/code snippets mentioned here  https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/api/?language=ruby does my app/company still has to be PCI compliant?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the direct tokenization method via the Ruby gem, the credit card information is going to be submitted to your servers in a request and then sent to Balanced. If any credit card information touches your servers, you have PCI compliance liability. Balanced recommends you use balanced.js. When used correctly, it enables this information to be securely transmitted directly to Balanced without ever touching your servers, thereby lessening your PCI compliance burden.

balanced.js is relatively trivial to integrate and also is extremely helpful in combating fraud. I recommend you follow their guide, https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/guides/balanced-js/

Comment: thanks much. BTW, the rentmybikes app has been helpful too :).